# Is it ok to use JPrintJob.print() in the Event Dispatch Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, printing

That's my question.

Should the print() method of a Printable object be run in another thread or maybe in a thread pool, or there's no problem in executing it in the EDT ?

Comment: I didn't find that question, thank you for showing it. 

So in fact it should be recommended to do it in another thread (despite if we use PrintDialog or not), considering that the Graphics object processing may be a long task.

Comment: I'd say that showing the print dialog should be shown in the EDT and the actually print should be thread - IMHO